# M bounded if and only if $\sup\{|\langle x,y \rangle|:y\in M \}<\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Show that $M\subset H$ is bounded if and only if $\sup\{|\langle x,y \rangle|:y\in M\}<\infty$ for every $x\in H$

My attempt:

Since $H$ is a Hilbert space any set is bounded if and only if it is weak bounded, hence

$$\forall\lambda\in X'\exists c_{\lambda}>0:\sup_{x\in M}|\lambda(x)|\leq c_{\lambda} $$

For each lambda we have a $x_T$ such that $\lambda(x)=\langle x,x_T \rangle$ for all $x\in H$. Since $\lambda$ is bounded on $M$ this does also hold for $\langle x,x_T \rangle$.

Just an idea. Can someone look at it and improve it? The hint also tells that we should use the uniform boundedness principle but in which step?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean for every $x\in M$, the supremum in your first line is finite?

Comment: I fixed it :) see above.

Comment: In the future, use \langle ($\langle$) and \rangle ($\rangle$) in place of $<$ and $>$ in inner products. $\langle$ and $\rangle$ look much cleaner.

Comment: Also I think the UBP is used to show one direction of your claim that a set is bounded iff it is weakly bounded.